# Ubuntu hotspot using TP-Link Archer T6E AC 1300 does not work on 18.04

Tags: wireless, ap-hotspot, tp-link

The hotspot feature works with an old Sitecom Wireless USB Adapter 300N X3. No additional installations necessary. My phone is able to discover and connect to the hotspot.

As I required more speed I bought the T6E pci card having read this device being supported natively on 18.04.
I installed the drivers via "Software and updates".
The card works with my 5G signal and is faster than the Sitecom.

I have a desktop pc, GA-770TA-UD3 motherboard, AMD.

Unfortunately the T6E does not work with the hotspot feature in Ubuntu. When the hotspot is turned on the GUI shows the SSID and password. The password is WEP encrypted where the Sitecom offers WPA. My phone is unable to discover the network.

Link to wireless info, using the Sitecom usb adapter with hotspot: 
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cjj55RQ7bJ/

Link to wireless info, using the T6E with hotspot: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/k5pghWqNnG/

lspci | grep -i Network
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)

First guess:
The bcmwl-kernel-source(proprietary) does not support AP mode for the BCM4360 chipset...

Is it possible to install other firmware that will support the AP mode?